# How can I turn a creature with Su and Ex abilties into armour that grants those abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting, armor

Could someone describe to me a method for changing a corporeal creature with Supernatural and Extraordinary racial abilities into a set of armor that would grant those same racial abilities to the wearer?

Neither the setting, nor the magic, nor crafting matter so long as it is not built from an inherited template, as I am trying to achieve something unique to happen in game.  I am imagining that it would work similarly to Fusion Spell for Psionics.

I am the DM for one scenario and would be a player for another.

**DM PoV**

I need to create a villain whose in game & story abilities can be defeated by destroying different sections of the armor, which can cost any amount but not be made of a material that is so unbreakable that it could not be destroyed. The details would be tailored to whatever they are wearing.

I'm designing an NPCs as if he were originally a Player Character. In terms of Su & Ex abilities, armor that grants the wearer Mountain Walk or Awesome Beauty, or something more random is what my concept needs.  This isn't about focusing on the numbers or what the story would look like, I don't have strong preferences: it is about having fun.  In creating the NPC, I hope to be able to create multiple other NPCs that use different methods as part of a group the party must face.

Examples:

1. The villain sends some would-be adventurer to gather his materials
   for him or
2. A hero decides to join forces with a dying whachamacallit.

Notes:

- Rough Cost Estimate: equivalent to the party's current collective
  fortune of 900,000 gp.
- Armor quality would be masterwork.
- The current party is equivalent to a level 20 party.

**Player Character POV**

Meanwhile from a player character's PoV, this character benefits others by creating that  sort of armor during the main campaign.

Comment: This is a thing that could probably be answered, but there are no guarantees that you'll like the answer. We can probably be more helpful if you told us about the “something weird” you're trying to accomplish and the planning problem this armour scheme is supposed to solve. Then we can help with *that* problem, instead of just how to execute on the solution you think might (but might not) solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe you could pick a creature or two with abilities that you would like to see for us to work on?

Comment: Are you the DM, or a player? Do you want a method that works in-game, or do you just want a description of how to create a set of armour that gives specific Ex and Su abilities to the wearer? And as GreySage asked, could you specify which creature you want to do this to, and which abilities you want the armour to have?

Comment: Is this a crunchy rules question specific to 3.5, looking for multipliers and such to cost out a "craft magic item," or a more story-based question?  As others have said, we need a few more details to tailor our answers for what you need.  I'll provide both answers below.

Comment: @NewDMLorev I assume you are the same user as OP. You should see about merging the two accounts, so that you can edit your own question without going through a queue. It will also allow you to respond in the comments to your own question.

Comment: IF the edit somehow missed something important (the prose was not clean) please revert or update the edit. Even with the edit, this question could use a bit more clarity.  Please be more definite about what it is that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a question about crunchy rules and numbers, I'd just go with the standard "estimate based on similar powered items" approach.  Example, if the Su ability keeps you from being paralysed or grappled, cost it like enchanting an item with "Freedom of Movement" and so forth.

From a story perspective, it's actually more interesting.   Magic is magic, and a case could be made that the skin of a monster could confer the Su power just with "Craft Magic Arms and Armor."  That seems thematic and story-appropriate.  The Ex ability is a little more odd.

If the critter had Extraordinary dodge for example, that's a case of its muscles and agility and whatever.  Ex abilities are explicitly *not* magical in nature.  So to make magic armor that grants an Ex ability, as a GM, I'd like to see some sort soul-binding magic involved.  If you like the Psionics Fusion spell for this, that sounds fine.

Personally, I'd go for the story-based idea.  Maybe you have to make armor out of the skin first, that grants the Su bonus, then the player has to go and kill an other of the same critter while wearing the skin of the first, to trigger some sort of soul-capture / power stealing magic, to complete the armor, granting it the Ex bonus by "stealing" it from the living creature.

Hey, nobody said it would be easy.

Comment: Don't answer unclear questions with a request for clarification; leave a comment instead

Comment: (and vote to close when you have enough rep)

Comment: Thanks @thedarkwanderer I have edited my response as you suggested, and put my request for clarification in in a comment.

Comment: Curious about the downvote.  I'm happy to edit answer, as I did for @thedarkwanderer suggestion.  My goal is to help the original questioner, but I can't improve my answer unless folks tell me what's wrong wit it.

Comment: It's possible that the downvote is just to express displeasure with attempting to answer a question before it's clear.

Comment: Thanks @SevenSidedDie , that hadn't occurred to me.  I figured answers to either interpretation would be a _good_ thing.

Comment: @JesseM One of the goals of the SE format is to reduce “noise” — information that isn't directly on-target for answer a question — and maximising “signal”, so that it's easier to both find what you're looking for and understand it once you've found it. Having multiple answers to multiple possible questions reduces that signal strength. So though it might be in theory good by some measure, it's not necessarily so in this particular context.

Comment: Fair enough criticism.  I sit corrected.